# Lightbox in aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, lightbox

I am trying to incorporate lightbox plugin with my aspx page to load a image. I have a master file and I have included the references of lightbox and jquery javascript files and css files in it.

I have a div element in which i have a text specified and on clicking the text i need the light box plugn show the image.

Please find the code below of aspx page.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        javascript: window.history.forward(1);
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#frame a').lightBox();
        });
    </script>
    <center>
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
 <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
 <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
 <aside class="right-side">
 <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
 <section class="content-header">
 <h1>
 </h1>
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li class="active">Student Details</li>
  <li><a href="/AcuityBase/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
  <br>
   Last Updated on : 01 Jan 2015 Hrs CST </br>
 </ol>
 </section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 connectedSortable">
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
 </div>
 <br />
 <!-- /.row -->
 <!-- Main row -->
 <div class="row">
  <!-- Left col -->
  <section class="col-lg-6 connectedSortable">
  <!-- Box (with bar chart) -->
  <div id="loading-example">
   <div class="box-body no-padding">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-7">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </section>
 </div>
 <section class="content">
 <ul id="tabs">
 </ul>
 <div id="content">
  <p>
   <a class="frame" data-lightbox="example-set" href= "content/img/avatar3.png"> Load Tableau Report</a>
  </p>
 </div>
 <div id="tab1">
  <div id="tab2">
  </div>
  <div id="tab3">
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- top row -->
 <!-- /.row -->
 </section>
 <!-- /.content -->
 </aside>
</div>
</center>
</asp:Content>
```

I have included the refences of the jquery and lightbox plugin in the master file along with the lightbox css. The code is below

```html
<!-- LightBox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="content/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="content/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

when i click on the text, its loading the image in the same window and not in a lightbox type.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You use a wrong selector to init your lightbox.

Currently :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#frame a').lightBox();
        });
</script>
```

Insteaf of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('a.frame').lightBox();
        });
</script>
```